# How can I rename a sensor's android device name?

Tags: java, android, sensors

I want to programatically change a [Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) name, more specifically, I want to Rename it.

Is it possible to change it's name, and if so how can I do it?

Because I can change the value "Android.os.Build.Product" by renaming "ro.product.name" in the file "build.prop" in "system" folder. So is there any similar ways to rename the sensor?

Comment: Have you code something until now? It would be useful to add it to your question.

Comment: Please narrow your problem for us with some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally can't see how can be useful to change a Sensor name, but anyway, it's not possible. The [Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) framework from android can be used only for the following tasks:

- Determine which sensors are available on a device.
- Determine an individual sensor's capabilities, such as its maximum range, manufacturer, power requirements, and resolution.
- Acquire raw sensor data and define the minimum rate at which you acquire sensor data.
- Register and unregister sensor event listeners that monitor sensor changes.

You can also refer to the [Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) api docs and see that the only method which uses the name is read only: `getName()` and thus, you simply can't  change a Sensor name.

Comment: I can change the value "Android.os.Build.Product" by renaming "ro.product.name" in the file "build.prop" in "system" folder. So is there any similar ways to rename the sensor?

Comment: No, even using the properties from build file.